# Pass by reference confusion?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, raw-pointer

Consider this example:

```
void MyFunction(int &x){...}

void MyOtherFunction(int *x){...}

int main()
{
  int my_variable = 10;
  MyFunction(my_variable);
  MyOtherFunction(&my_variable);
}
```

Am I right in saying both the these methods are passing the variable by reference (i.e. not creating a copy), and the only difference is that MyOtherFunction is receiving a pointer?

Comment: Yup. A pointer is a type of reference.

Comment: The generated code will show no difference at all. The only practical differences are that a pointer can be null and that in the pointer case the compiler will allow it to be reassigned, which is illegal for references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in saying that you don't copy `my_variable`, but a [pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) is not a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), they're two sets of distinct types.

For example, a pointer can be null and you can call `MyOtherFunction(nullptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no copy. Passing a pointer means you can pass a null ptr, while using a reference you must pass a valid object.

For int, float and simple vars, passing by value is not more expensive, provided you don't need to change inside the function the passed parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, you are never copying `my_variable` (although you are copying a pointer when you call `void MyOtherFunction(int *x){...}`, but that is fine).

The important difference between the two functions is that `MyFunction(int &x)` is a proper C++ reference and would never be null (in normal code), whereas you can pass nullptr `MyOtherFunction(int *x)`, and this must be checked at runtime. The pointer version can also be re-assigned inside `MyOtherFunction` as required.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. In the both calls you are passing the variable by reference. However this term by reference in C++ differs form the same term in C.

In C when someone says that he passed an argument by reference it means that it passed a pointer to the variable.

In C++ references have a new meaning. They are a part of the specification of the language. So when someone says that he passed an argument by reference then usually it means that the corresponding parameter is declared like reference.:)

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference is the alias to `orignal object`. Pass by pointer creates the extra variable to hold the address of `original object`.